# Override method/variable in a gem rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actiondispatch, ndjson

I am trying to find a way to override a variable in a rails gem `actionpack/http/parameters.rb`. I have to process an [ndjson](http://ndjson.org) stream and the rails middleware cannot process `ndjson`. It uses `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode`

This is the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7387b85ebb4a3f2ba909009210fb3ca4302733cf/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb#L10-L15) of the code below

```
  DEFAULT_PARSERS = {
    Mime[:json].symbol => -> (raw_post) {
      data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw_post)
      data.is_a?(Hash) ? data : { _json: data }
    }
  }
```

I get this error when it tries to parse ndjson

```
ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError in MyController#activity
```

My objective is to override the parser to allow it to decode the ndjson... Potentially using `split(\n)` as opposed to the current `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode`.

So far i have tried creating a file in `lib/` folder and using the following code but it doesn't seem to do the override. How do i do this without Monkey patching

```
require 'lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters'

module MyParser
  module Overrides
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    DEFAULT_PARSERS = {
        Mime[:json].symbol => -> (raw_post) {
          data = raw_post.split("\n")
          data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(data)
          data.is_a?(Hash) ? data : { _json: data }
        }
    }

  end
end

ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters.include(MyParser::Overrides)
```

UPDATE:

The second approach i tried:

```
ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters.const_set(:DEFAULT_PARSERS, {
  Mime[:json].symbol => -> (raw_post) {
    data = raw_post.split("\n")
    data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(data)
    data.is_a?(Hash) ? data : { _json: data }
  },
})
```

Unfortunately it keeps warning me that the constant is already defined.

Comment: Without monkey patching, you’d need to write something on top of it which uses the send method to call lots of internal methods. I don’t really recommend it.

Comment: Doesn't ndjson have its own mime type that you can use instead of monkeying around in the Rails internals? I don't really get the point in responding to ndjson requests in the first place through.

Comment: Max, i can't find any ndjson mime type, and furthermore, it it did exist, the middleware would still throw an error. Unless i monkey patch the mime

Answer (score 0):

I took another approach. Instead of reinitializing the constant, i created a file in `config/initializers/custom_params.rb` to override the method `parse_formatted_parameters` ([here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/11738e82cdcfb48f7740a2da01ad2716d9bcfbb6/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb#L87-L98)) that was using the `DEFAULT_PARSERS` variable. From within i was able to change the Proc value for the `json` data type.

This conveniently overrides the method  and allows the `ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters` module to pass the `ndjson` to my controller without any parsing errors.

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Http
    module Parameters
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      private

      def parse_formatted_parameters(parsers)
        parsers[Mime[:json].symbol] = Proc.new { |raw_post|
            data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw_post) rescue nil
            if !data
              data = raw_post
            end
            data.is_a?(Hash) ? data : { _json: data }
          }

        return yield if content_length.zero? || content_mime_type.nil?
        # rubocop:enable all

        strategy = parsers.fetch(content_mime_type.symbol) { return yield }

        begin
          strategy.call(raw_post)
        rescue # JSON or Ruby code block errors.
          my_logger = logger || ActiveSupport::Logger.new($stderr)
          my_logger.debug "Error occurred while parsing request parameters.\nContents:\n\n#{raw_post}"

          raise ParseError
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```